# How to get a person that has multiple diseases

Tags: sql

Im trying to find a person that both has Insomnia and the flu.

The code that I've tried so far is:

```
SELECT Patient.patientName, Patient.patientPNbr
FROM Patient
LEFT JOIN SuffersFrom
ON Patient.patientPNbr = SuffersFrom.patientPNbr
WHERE diseaseName = 'Insomnia'
AND diseaseName = 'Influenza'
```

How would you proceed to find the person?

Comment: Check out 'Group by' and 'having' keywords...

Comment: which database are you using? . because your sql looks fine

Comment: Just go into the waiting room and look for the tired person that is sneezing

Comment: @EdHeal Ohh you beat me... I wanted to write the same when I saw the question's title in the overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this if want to return patients who has both disease

```
SELECT Patient.patientName, Patient.patientPNbr
FROM Patient
INNER JOIN SuffersFrom ON Patient.patientPNbr = SuffersFrom.patientPNbr
WHERE diseaseName IN ('Insomnia','Influenza')
GROUP BY Patient.patientName, Patient.patientPNbr
HAVING COUNT(diseaseName)>1
```

Comment: One potential issue with this is that if there are two entries for Insomnia (or two for Influenza) in the SuffersFrom table then this would also return a result.

Comment: Then you can use DISTINCT in the COUNT as 'HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT diseaseName)>1'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `SuffersFrom` multiple times (once per disease you're checking). I'd use the `EXISTS` clause.

```
SELECT SELECT Patient.patientName, Patient.patientPNbr
FROM Patient
--Check for Insomnia
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM SuffersFrom
    WHERE Patient.patientPNbr = SuffersFrom.patientPNbr
    AND diseaseName = 'Insomnia')
--Check for Influenza
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM SuffersFrom
    WHERE Patient.patientPNbr = SuffersFrom.patientPNbr
    AND diseaseName = 'Influenza')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query with joins ...

```
       SELECT P.patientName, P.patientPNbr
       FROM Patient p
             INNER JOIN SuffersFrom s
                  ON p.patientPNbr = s.patientPNbr
             INNER JOIN SuffersFrom s1
                  ON s.patientPNbr = s1.patientPNbr   
        WHERE s.diseaseName = 'Insomnia'
               AND s1.diseaseName = 'Influenza'
```